# Query a Postgresql table using variable in R

Tags: r

I have a few tablea in my postgresql database with names similar to: `"114114.KP"`. I would like to dynamically call the table from R using RPostgres package. 
I know that the name of the table makes it difficult to process. But is there a way to do it pls?

What I did so far, with `i = "114114.KP"` :

```
  if(dbExistsTable(con5, i) == TRUE){
    ExistingPortfolios <- dbSendQuery(con3, paste("SELECT * from \"", i,"\""))
    ExistingPortfolios <- fetch(ExistingPortfolios)
  }
```

But this returns an error (which is normal):

```
>     ExistingPortfolios <- dbSendQuery(con3, paste("SELECT * from \"", i,"\""))
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (connection with pending rows, close resultSet before continuing)
```

Comment: I would appreciate any help on this little challenge please. Unless nobody has come across such situation in the past